# Fallo al comparar los valores de un JSpinner. JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

Tengo 2 spinner, cada uno con sus valores correspondientes sacados de un string:

```
        SpinnerListModel pal = new SpinnerListModel(palabras );
        spinner = new javax.swing.JSpinner(pal);
        SpinnerListModel word = new SpinnerListModel(words);
        spinner1 = new javax.swing.JSpinner(word);
```

y estas son las arrays que están declaradas previamente:

```
static String palabras[] = {"hola", "manzana", "leon", "castillo", "videojuego"};
    static String words[] = {"hello", "apple", "lion", "castle", "videogame"};
```

Mi problema surge cuando intento comparar los valores que tienen en el spinner, cuando presiono un boton obtengo los valores de la siguiente forma:

```
private void btnComprobarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        //prueba.setText(String.valueOf(spinner.getValue()));
        if(String.valueOf(spinner).equals("hola")&& String.valueOf(spinner1).equals("hello")){
            prueba.setText("Correcto");
        }
    }
```

Si obtengo el valor y lo muestro en el texto muestra la palabra que contiene en el momento, pero si los comparo no muestra nada, que puede estar fallando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es que no lo estás comparando de la misma forma que lo obtienes, fíjate en tu código:

```
private void btnComprobarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    //prueba.setText(String.valueOf(spinner.getValue())); GETVALUE()
    if(String.valueOf(spinner).equals("hola") && 
       String.valueOf(spinner1).equals("hello")){ //aquí no usas el getValue()
        prueba.setText("Correcto");
    }
}
```

Lo que estás haciendo dentro del `if` es comparar lo siguiente:
`if(JSpinner.valueOf()  == "cadena de texto)`, no estás comparando el valor, sino el objeto en forma de `String.valueOf()`

Prueba con esto, que debería de funcionar:

```
private void btnComprobarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if(String.valueOf(spinner.getValue()).equals("hola")) && 
       String.valueOf(spinner1.getValue()).equals("hello")){ 
        prueba.setText("Correcto");
    }
}
```

Comment: No me puedo creer que me haya dejado un error tan tonto, madre mia como estoy... Gracias por la correción

Comment: @AlbertoMartínez a todos nos pasa ;) A seguir a por el Jueves